# How to tell GCC never unroll a loop?

Tags: c, gcc

I understand that GCC can specifically unroll a loop, but how can I tell GCC never unroll a loop?

I'm not sure:
1) if the -O0 will force gcc never unroll loops in a program. 
2) How to tell GCC to specifically avoid unrolling a loop in a function?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry, my answer about #pragma Loop_optimize was about GNAT  (Ada), not C

Comment: @EugeneSh.: And in Ada it's `pragma`, not `#pragma`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm measuring the system performance, e.g., cache performance under specific access pattern. I don't want the GCC optimization does any fancy job that changes the (access) pattern I want.

Comment: @KeithThompson Maybe for curiosity's sake! :)

Comment: I didn't answer it, because I'm not sure if it'll work --- but have you tried putting your loop into a separate (force-inline) function and adding `__attribute__((optimize("no-unroll-loops")))` --- should (**in theory**) be equivalent to `-fno-unroll-loops` as an argument, except only applied to that function.

Comment: Addendum to my above post: For force-inline, you'll also need `inline` attribute (standard C) and `__attribute__((always_inline))`. Yes, you need both (at least according to the docs).

Comment: Have you checked -Os ? I'm not sure it will never unroll loops but since size is the focus, I guess it could be the case.

Comment: If you can control the factor of unroll, then set it to 1x.

Comment: In the texinfo manual for GCC, the `-funroll-loops` option is not designated among those included at *any* numbered optimization level, so I conclude that you don't get it unless you specifically ask for it.  However, there are other optimizations on loops that are enabled at level `-O` == `-O1` and higher.  If you don't want *any* optimizations performed on your loops, then your best bet is probably to compile with `-O0`.